# JPA Repository - built-in query (like findbyId) doesn't work after adding a function with custom query

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am currently developing using Spring and JPA Repository in my application.

I originally had a function called `findById` and recently added a function named `findByLanguage` as shown below.

`findById` worked before I added `findByLanguage`.

After adding `findByLanguage`, `findById` executes the SQL query defined in `findByLanguage` not the native built-in one.

Does anyone know why it's doing this?

```java
public interface StoreTypeCodeRepository extends JpaRepository<StoreTypeCode, UUID> {

  @Query("SELECT new xyz.hitit.store.dto.storetypecode.StoreTypeCodeResult(STC.id, STC.displaySort, COALESCE(SC1.type1, SC2.type1), COALESCE(SC1.type2, SC2.type2))\n"
      + "FROM StoreTypeCode STC\n"
      + "LEFT JOIN STC.storeTypeCodeTranslationList SC1 ON SC1.lang = ?1\n"
      + "LEFT JOIN STC.storeTypeCodeTranslationList SC2 ON SC2.isDefault = TRUE\n"
      + "WHERE STC.isEnabled = TRUE\n"
      + "ORDER BY STC.displaySort ASC")
  List<StoreTypeCodeResult> findByLanguage(String language);

  Optional<StoreTypeCode> findById(UUID userid);


}
```

Comment: can you show the code you are running and the log demonstrating it executes the wrong query?

Comment: JPA have `findById` method in-built. There is no need to define it explicitly.

Comment: You don't have to write `findById` method in your repository.